# Adressing the next higher Element in Template.events

Tags: javascript, meteor, checkbox, meteor-blaze

I have a List of Checkbox groups. Each Checkbox group has a name.
I display them by iterating over the list. 
Now when i want to update the checkboxes for each individual checkbox group (which have the same schema) by using "this", i only get the information about the corresponding checkbox.
How can i get the checkboxes group name?

Schema:

```
CheckboxSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    label: "Name"
  },
  checked: {
    type: Boolean,
    label: "Checked",
    defaultValue: false
  }
});

GroupSchema = new SimpleSchema(
listName: {
    type: String,
    label: "GroupName"
  },
  checkboxes: {
    type: [CheckboxSchema]
  }
}]);
```

In the events i want to access the id of each Checkbox group to pass it to Meteor.call to update the values of each checkbox to its corresponding group.

```
Template.checkboxGroup.events({
"click .toggle-checked": function(event) {
    var self = this;
    event.preventDefault();
    // Need checkbox group id
    Meteor.call("setCheckboxgroup", self._id, !self.checked);
}
```

});

Thanks in advance!
Vin

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get it like this:

```
var group = Groups.findOne({ checkboxes: self._id });
var groupId = "";
if( group ) {
  groupId = group._id;
}

if( groupId ) {
  Meteor.call("setCheckboxgroup", self._id, !self.checked);
}
```

If that doesn't work, I believe you need to use $elemMatch.